# Are random variables generated from a gaussian copula necessarily gaussian random variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-generation, copula

The Gauss copula is defined implicitly from the multivariate normal distribution, that is, the Gauss copula is the copula associated with a multivariate normal distribution. where the inputs of the Multivariate normal are inverses of normal CDFs. However, if the inputs are not inverses of a normal CDF does it imply that the joint distribution does follow a multivariate normal distribution? if not great! but why? any textbook or a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: could the distribution be multinormal if either of the marginals is *discrete*?  In fact, if the marginals have *any* distribution besides normal distributions, could the joint distribution possibly be multinormal?

Comment: @whuber I guess no. I know it is no but is there any clear reference book or article you may refer me too? just for citation

Comment: A good reference is Nelsen's Introduction to Copulas - https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Copulas-Springer-Statistics/dp/0387286594

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A copula defines the relationship between variates with *uniform* margins, so an untransformed Gaussian copula is itself an obvious answer to your question (its margins must be uniform, since that's a property of a copula). Consequently, any text that actually has a definition of a copula would serve as a reference.

Any subsequent transform of the margins of that copula other than a transformation to normality will leave you with some other non-normal margin. For example, a logit transformation $X=\log(\frac{U}{1-U})$, $Y=\log(\frac{V}{1-V})$ would leave you with logistic margins but the copula itself will be unchanged by any marginal transformation.

Indeed, this is the very *point* of using copulas - being able to describe the dependence structure independently of the particular marginal distributions.